# NextJS GetStaticProps and GetStaticPaths authentication

Tags: next.js

I'm using NextJS and I have a doubt.

My app has an page like this

```
/supperter/[id]
```

where I have to be authenticated to render it.

I did all the auth part, and it works perfectly for every other page I have except this one because I don't have any chance to access the cookie that is setted up to access the backend.

```
export async function getStaticPaths() {
  const resProducts = await fetch(`${process.env.PRIVATE_ENDPOINT}/developers`, {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'myToken', // I NEED TO ACCESS TO THE AUTH RIGHT HERE
    },
  });
  const assignments = await resProducts.json();
  const paths = assignments.data.map((p) => ({
    params: {
      id: p.id.toString(),
    },
  }));
  return {
    // this should be dynamic
    paths,
    fallback: true,
  };
}
```

is there any chance to achiieve this? I already know that this is serverside BUT I NEED IT.

thanks in advance.

PS: Next sometimes is so unuseful

Comment: Isn't your token accessible on the server side? Maybe through the database? If this is server side, can't you just access the database directly?

Comment: it's an outside api. imposible. I hate next. I don't recommend it at all

Comment: If you're generating static pages you'll have to do the authentication on the client-side. `getStaticPaths` gets called on the server at build time during the static pages generation.